# Removing OpenSuse packages from SUSE 11 sp 4 (SLES) saftly?

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

I have SUSE 11 sp 4 for SAP Apps . (SAP HANA installed on it)
mistakenly ,i did

> zypper update

from OpenSuse repo , that was very big mistake.

> /bin/rpm -qa --queryformat "%{DISTRIBUTION}\n" | sort | uniq (none) 
>   SUSE Linux Enterprise 11
>   openSUSE 11.4

and i found too much packages installed/replaced from  opensuse repo

that , many apps are crashed , also x11 doesn't working .

How can i resolve this issue saftly without damage the SAP HANA Server ? and What if i selected "Repair Installed System" and Customized Repair for  package database option from SLES DVD  ? would it help to solve the issue ?

Comment: theoretically remove openSUSE repository and run `zypper dup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove openSUSE related repositories with `zypper rr` command and then `zypper dup` ( dist upgrade command which allows change of vendor and downgrade of packages)